# Express taking forever to load mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, database-connection

I'm trying to query a single line from a 28k record database as a test but it isn't going through but when I load up 'localhost:3001/api/get' it stays loading, even though my connection says success? Is it actually even connecting to the db?

my data bases schema is:

id | state_name | city

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "states_city"
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.get('/api/get', (req, res)=>{
    const sqlGet = "SELECT city FROM state_city city = 'Chicago'";
    db.query(sqlGet, (err, res)=>{
        console.log("success");
    });
});

app.listen(3001, ()=>{
    console.log("running on port 3001");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you must make server running. Remove that API route you had set before running server.

```js
    app.listen(3001, ()=>{
        console.log("running on port 3001");
    });
```

Now you must create database connection. Create new file `dbconn.js`

```js
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    
    const db = mysql.createPool({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "password",
        database: "states_city"
    });
```

Now create new connection:

```js
    var new_connection = mysql.createPool(
      db
    );
    
    new_connection.on('connection', function (connection) {
      console.log('DB Connection established');
    
      connection.on('error', function (err) {
        console.error(new Date(), 'MySQL error', err.code);
      });
      connection.on('close', function (err) {
        console.error(new Date(), 'MySQL close', err);
      });
    
    });
    
    // export connection
    module.exports = new_connection;
```

Include that connection in other file:

```js
    var db_connection = require('../dbconn');
    db_connection.query(query, params, function (error, results, fields) {
        //Do your query
    });
```

Read about [project structure](https://softwareontheroad.com/ideal-nodejs-project-structure/) to make your code easy to edit.